# Property 'location' does not exist on type 'typeof window'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My code was working until I upgraded the typescript and react frameworks.This error is happening on the line   **window.location.assign("#/home/dashboard");**. I have read articles but still cannot resolve the issue. I also think the window property is from **modernizer.js.**
 Currently, the error I have been getting when I try to run the project is below:

> TS2339: Property 'location' does not exist on type 'typeof window'.

This is the code below

```
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";
import {ActionLockOutline, SocialPerson} from "material-ui/svg-icons";
import * as React from "react";
import {hot} from "react-hot-loader";
import { OAuth } from "../../Shared/Services/OAuth";
import { Component, IComponentState } from "../../Shared/Utilities/Component";
import { Log } from "../../Shared/Utilities/LogUtil";
import { Validation } from "../../Shared/Utilities/Validation";

// import { StorageUtil } from "../../Shared/Utilities/StorageUtil";

interface ILoginState extends IComponentState {
    userName: string;
    password: string;
}

class Form extends Component<any, ILoginState> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props,
            {
                password: "",
                userName: "",
            });

    }

    public loginClick = () => {
        // this.warningNoti("All fields marked red are required");

        if (Validation.formValidation("#loginForm")) {
            OAuth.userLogin(this.state.userName, this.state.password, (loginResponse: any) => {
                Log.consoleObj(loginResponse);

                this.successNoti("User successfully logged in");

                window.location.assign("#/home/dashboard");

            }, (status: string, jqXhr: any) => {
                // console.log(status);
                // console.log(jqXhr);
                this.setState({password: ""});
                this.infoNoti("Incorrect username or password, please check credentials.");
            });
        } else {
            this.warningNoti("All fields marked red are required");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using react-router? In that case the idiomatic way to navigate would be `this.props.history.push('/new/route/here')`

Comment: Yes I'm using react-router. You want me to use the code you sent to redirect the page?

Comment: Yes, you can use the code above in place of window.location.assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Answering your question: Why tslint raises that "Property 'location' does not exist on type 'window'. It is because Typescript has some set of types defined, default types and custom types. For typescript window is custom type. Default types are number, string,boolean,any,etc. So when you want to use window, it is treated as a window object which has functions like assign, location and so on defined as interface in default lib.dom.d.ts. For now I suggest a work around for you by creating a const with type set as any.
reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html 
Solution/Workaround: set type of your constant by yourself by doing this :

```
const temp: any = window;
temp.location.assign('#/home/dashboard');
```

Comment: Your suggestion removed the errors but now webpack.config.js also generates errors for the path,"Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.".Now this one too is confusing

Comment: sorry but further I can't assist as I have limited knowledge of webpack :(